# Content of input file into array bootstrap and php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using this code to input a file:

```
<label class="control-label">Select File</label>
<input id="input-1" type="file" class="file">
```

But how can i save the content of the input file into a php array and output the content?

The file is something like this:

```
name1
name2
name3
```

Comment: You need to make two steps from this. Do you want to immediately parse the file/asynchronus (in this case, ajax?). If not. Just upload the file. The file will be placed in the PHP's `tmp` folder and you can parse it. Like with `file_get_contents()`

Comment: i don't need ajax. When i'm doing this `$file = file_get_contents('./test.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH); `  and `var_dump($file);` i'm getting `bool(false)`

Comment: you should have posted the full html for this, including the php, since you tagged as such. There's most likely a duplicate for it already, given you didn't name your input and would have clearly thrown an undefined index notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, give a name to file field, like:

```
<input id="input-1" name="uploaded-file" type="file" class="file">
```

Then, use `$_FILES` superglobal in your php file to access it:

```
$content = file_get_contents($_FILES['uploaded-file']['tmp_name']);
```

Read [PHP: Handling file uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) for more info.

Comment: when i ´var_dump($content);´ it's return ´bool(false) ´

Comment: It is necessary to see the complete code to understand what is wrong in your case. I can try to assume that when the form is declared, you are not specifying enctype property: for file uploading it should be set like this: `<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: Ǹice! It was that! Thank you very much!